# No output is displayed on console for \b character

Tags: c++, centos

The following code snippet is not printing anything in each iteration of the while loop. The actual output is printed at the end of the program execution only. This problem is encountered in CentOS only where as in Windows the code snippet works as expected.

```
std::cout << "Test \\b functionality: ";
int count = 0;
std::cout << count;
while (count < 10)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << std::string(std::to_string(count).length(), '\b');
    std::cout << ++count;
}
```

**Removing** "`std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));`" **statement** **prints the output on each iteration.**

Expected Output:
On each iteration console should output new count value after erasing old count value. In other terms, the console should show latest value of count variable.

Comment: stdout is line-buffered by default. try `std::cout << ++count << std::flush` or use [std::unitbuf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf)  to automatically flush after every write

Comment: @Botje To be a little picky, it's the `FILE*` named `stdout` that is line-buffered (unless it's not connected to a terminal in which case it's fully buffered). `std::cout` itself is fully buffered, but since it's usually connected to `stdout` it's in practice also line-buffered (unless not connected to a terminal, as mentioned).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right. I should have mentioned `setvbuf` somewhere too :)

Comment: Has nothing to do with `\b`. You should have tried removing it see whether it was related to the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::cout` is a buffered stream and as such you must `flush` it in order to guarantee writing data before a `close`:

```
std::cout << std::string(std::to_string(count).length(), '\b') << std::flush;
std::cout << ++count << std::flush;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses, using std::flush is working fine.